# Scraping ASP.NET Page - Next Button Click

Tags: asp.net, scrapy

I am scraping an ASP.net page with Scrapy which displays a paginated list of items. To navigate through the items, there are next and previous buttons in the following format:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="POST" action="search_active_main.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
    <!-- other content here -->

    <!-- previous button -->
    <input type="image" name="ctl00$gvMain$ctl01$btnPrevious" id="ctl00_gvMain_ctl01_btnPrevious" src="/image/previous.gif" />
    <!-- next button -->
    <input type="image" name="ctl00$gvMain$ctl01$btnNext" id="ctl00_gvMain_ctl01_btnNext" src="/image/next.gif" />

    <!-- other content here -->
</form>
```

When you click one of the buttons, something like this is sent as part of the POST:

```
ctl00$gvMain$ctl01$btnNext.x:37
ctl00$gvMain$ctl01$btnNext.y:10
```

What do these numbers represent / how can I crawl through them without using something like Selenium?

Comment: Those numbers appear to represent co-ordinates. Try to click the very top left of the button and see what data is sent. Given the low value of both co-ords, I would expect you to see something close to x:0 y:0 (depending on how close to the corner you clicked).

Comment: Thanks this is right, in which case these numbers have nothing to do with how to crawl the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Obsidian Phoenix suggests, the numbers represent the coordinates of the button that is clicked. To crawl the page, you just have to POST the following as formdata in FormRequest to simulate a next button click:

```
FormRequest.from_response(
    response,
    formdata={
        'ctl00$gvMain$ctl01$btnNext.x':'1' 
        'ctl00$gvMain$ctl01$btnNext.y':'1'
    },
    dont_click=True,
    dont_filter=True,
    callback=self.your_callback_function
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to investigate is the URL that is present on each page. You may find subsequent pages have /2 /3 etc in their URL but otherwise be identical.

If that's the case, then you can bypass the need to click any buttons and just reload the page with the new page number.

Comment: The url does not change when the button is clicked

Comment: Thats unfortunate. I'll leave the answer up as it may be of use to others in future, but clearly it's not *your* answer. Unfortunately I don't know python/Scrapy, so can't contribute much more than that - I'll leave that to others.